# Echo to file with batch programing

Tags: file, batch-file, echo

I want to learn echo to file, with batch programing.

my batch :

```
@echo off
echo Hello World > c:\text.txt
```

Text.txt result :

```
Hello World
```

It is Seccessfully

But If my batch file (Added '"'):

```
 @echo off
 echo Hello '"' World > c:\text.txt
```

Result :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users>echo Hello '"' World > c:\text.txt
Hello '"' World > c:\text.txt
```

Why text.txt not created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should escape the single double quote:

```
echo Hello '^"' World>test.txt
```

otherwise the `echo` parser is waiting for the *closing* double quote and the `>` redirection remains escaped by quote.